# store values with localStorage

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, local-storage

I need some help here. Whit this page i want to create own link tags with a image. When you click your image, you'll go to that page you have choose. I think i'm almost done but it does not work! What have i done wrong?!
When I click the img element to open the new page, the image pops up..

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Min Startsida</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function newLink() {
            var myNewLink = document.getElementById("link");
                localStorage.setItem(link, myNewLink.value)
        };
        function newIcon() {
            var myNewIcon = document.getElementById("icon");
                localStorage.setItem(icon, myNewIcon.value)
        };
            function varIcon() {
                document.getElementById("image").src = localStorage.getItem(icon)
      };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <h1>lägg till länk</h1><br />
        <input type="text" id="link"><br />
        <input type="text" id="icon"><br />
        <button onClick="newLink(), newIcon()">lägg till länk</button>
    </form>
    <section>
        <a href="#" onClick="location.href = localStorage.getItem(link)"><img src="#" id="image" onLoad="varIcon()"></a>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: ty, but still not working..

Comment: In the localStorage resources files I only find the Link value, but the link value is what the image icon value is suppose to be   //btw sorry for bad english, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be a string:

```
localStorage.setItem("link", myNewLink.value)
                      ^^^^
```

what happens here is that the element is used as a key as link is used as an id - key has to be a string. This goes for both the `setItem` methods and the `getItem` as well that you use later:

```
<a href="#" onClick="location.href = localStorage.getItem('link')">
```

Alos, this must be separated with a semi-column:

```
 <button onClick="newLink(); newIcon()">
                           ^
```

(I didn't look further than these points)